# Dropdown (with id) within a Div (also with id) problem setting a value

Tags: python, html, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to use a daq.BooleanSwitch to show or hide a dropdown. In order to also hide the html.Label of said dropdown, I've given the Div an id. This way I can change the style of the Div from {'display':'block'} to {'display':'none'} and hide **both** the label and the dropdown.

**MY PROBLEM:**

-> Not giving the div an id, leads to only the dropdown beeing hidden, not the label.

--> Giving the div an id leads to this error for my dropdown value (value=5):

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
> string indices must be integers

Relevant code:

```
html.Div([
    daq.BooleanSwitch(
    id='hour_or_day',
    on=True,
    label='Hour/Day',
    labelPosition="bottom",
    color="#002255")])

html.Div( id= 'hide_choosehour' [
    html.Label('Choose hour:'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
    id='hourChoice',
    options=[{'label': str(i), 'value': str(i)} for i in range(24)],
    value = 5,
    )
], style= {'display':'block'})


@app.callback(
   Output('hide_choosehour', 'style'),
   Input('hour_or_day', 'on')
)

def show_hide_ChooseHour(on):
    if on:
        return {'display': 'none'}
    return {'display': 'block'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=8050, debug=True)
```

I have found a workaround, which is to not use a label or hmtl.P (and therefore the need for a div id is gone), but instead a placeholder with the text needed. Still curious though, as a label would be best. Any advice is welcome, give me a heads up if anything is unclear!

Comment: There are two issues with your code: You have duplicate IDs for the first Div and the Dropdown (`hour_or_day`). This causes a `DuplicateIdError`. Second, in the second div, there is a comma missing after the id, this is supposed to be `children=[...]`. Are both Divs supposed to be part of the `app.layout`?

Comment: Whoops. The duplicate was not in my orignial code, only this translated samplecode. However you helped me solve my issue! The missing comma was a problem, and the id was missplaced. I moved the id to after the div brackets [] and before style= .. this solved my issue! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the id of the div to after the brackets instead of before solved my issue!

```py
html.Div([
    html.Label('Choose hour:'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
    id='hourChoice',
    options=[{'label': str(i), 'value': str(i)} for i in range(24)],
    value = 5),
],id='hide_choosehour', style= {'display':'block'})
```